# ionic tabs background color

Tags: css, tabs

[image]

in above picture want to change the color of tabs(unclicked state) to some other.For example in above figure my home tab in at unclicked state.I has default color of dark grey.I wish to change its color to some other.Meanwhile I also wish to change color of text and the line(one that indicates which item tabs are clicked).I am new to ionic please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the icon is an SVG then just change the color of it by taking the id or class its wrapped in and in css do `color: green;`.  The same thing goes for the text.

Comment: I have used default icons available in ionicons.com .The above solution doesn't works for me

Comment: Ah ok... Sorry bout that but I got nothin

Answer (score 0):

This for others who will see this in future, it may solve your prob.

If you want to change the Icon colour you need to have different colour icons, and set them on sate .activated of tabs.
1)  This scenario will change your selected tab(text only) colour.

```
.tab-item.tab-item-active, .tab-item.active, .tab-item.activated{
    opacity: 1;
    color: #327FAF;
}
```

2)
For change selected tab background colour only use below snippet.

```
.tabs-top.tabs-striped .tab-item{
    background: #33cd5f;
}
```

Appreciate if helps.